# Error unable to find the package name called v8-devel on RHEL8

Tags: linux, rpm, rhel, libv8

I am trying to install v8-devel rpm package on RHEL 8.1 but unable to find it in all repositories of RHEL as well as in EPEL. I tried all the possibilities as shown below:

```
yum install v8-devel
yum install v8-devel
yum --enablerepo=* install v8*
yum search v8-devel
yum whatprovides v8-devel
dnf install v8-devel
dnf install v8-devel
dnf install v8*
```

i do have following EPEL for RHEL8 installed on my server.

```
 epel         
 epel-modular 
 epel-source
```

I am also able to install similar package on RHEL 7 with the help of EPEL.

I am just curious to know whether name of (v8-devel) got changed for RHEL8 or not?

Can someone help me to find out v8-devel rpm and install it via EPEL on RHEL8.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we talk about `R` package the way is to run `R` shell and exec command:

```
> install.packages("v8")
```

Comment: thanks. I am doing the same as mentioned above but still i am talking about rpm package.

Comment: @SantoshGarole, you can try, but I have my doubts you will find one.